# Facebook feed not working on wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I have a `word press` site where I need to display the `facebook` feed. I have installed the `Facebook plugin` for word press, I configured to show the desired facebook page feed, but it displays nothing. Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong?
[image]

This is the page where I need to display

```
        <div class="col-md-4">
            
        <div class="hidden-xs">
            <h1 id="tgb_head"><span id="facebook_icon" class="social-content-icon"></span> Facebook</h1>                 
            <div class="tab-content">
                
             <div class="tab-pane active fade in">
                <ul class="list-unstyled" id="facebook_ticker">
                    [custom-facebook-feed]
                </ul>
                </div>
              <div id="facebook_ticker_controls" class="ticker-controls">
                    <a href="#" class="prev pull-left" id="fprev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>&nbsp; Previous</a> 
                    <a href="#" class="next pull-right" id="fnext">Next &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span></a> 
       </div>
                  
       </div><!-- end tab-content -->
                
       </div><!-- end facebook -->
```

This is how it shows:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: WordPress shortcodes are only parsed in content you input in the editor and send through the content filter. You can not just write `[foo]` in your _template_, and expect that to parse the shortcode. You need to call `do_shortcode` in that place instead. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/shortcode-in-a-template/

Comment: This was the problem. Now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress shortcodes are only parsed in content you input in the editor and send through the content filter. You can not just write `[foo]` in your *template*, and expect that to parse the shortcode.

You need to call `do_shortcode` in that place instead.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/shortcode-in-a-template/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/